# Upload photo to Ubuntu server throught php in Android

Tags: php, android, mysql, image

I have to do an Android application, I have a problem with upload photos to a server. I've tried some examples but don't work.

My view consists in a button for select the image from the gallery or camera, then with another button I must upload to the server through php file.

My Android code is the following:

```
class ImageGalleryTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
   protected String doInBackground(Void... unsued) {
            InputStream is;
            BitmapFactory.Options bfo;
            Bitmap bitmapOrg;
            ByteArrayOutputStream bao ;

            bfo = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            bfo.inSampleSize = 2;
            //bitmapOrg = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + customImage, bfo);

            bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bao);
            byte [] ba = bao.toByteArray();
            String ba1 = Base64.encodeBytes(ba);
            ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fotoUp",ba1));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name","image_android"));
            Log.v("log_tag", System.currentTimeMillis()+".jpg");           
            try{
                    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpPost httppost = new 
                  //  Here you need to put your server file address
                    HttpPost("http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxx/upload_photo.php");
                    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    is = entity.getContent();
                    Log.v("log_tag", "Success" );
               }catch(Exception e){
                    Log.v("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
               }
        return "Success";
        // (null);
         }

             @Override
      protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... unsued) {
               }

      @Override
       protected void onPostExecute(String sResponse) {
        try {
            if (dialog.isShowing())
                dialog.dismiss();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    e.getMessage(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.e(e.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }
        }
```

and the php is:

```
$ruta = "photos/" . basename( $_FILES['fotoUp']['name']);
  if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fotoUp']['tmp_name'], $ruta))
    chmod ("uploads/".basename( $_FILES['fotoUp']['name']), 0644);
```

The application works but the image don't upload to server. I change the permissions in Ubuntu server to 777.

My Ubuntu server folder where I can upload the photo is located in var/www/xxxx/photos and the php file is in var/www/xxx/upload_photo.php

I also know to how can I save the path where is storaged in my mySQL database.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

This is my code for upload, and it's work. You need import [httpmime jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/h/Downloadhttpmime401jar.htm)

PHP code

```
$uploads_dir = '/Library/WebServer/Documents/Upload/upload/'.$_FILES['userfile']['name'];
if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'])) {
    echo $_POST["contentString"]."\n";
    echo  "File path = ".$uploads_dir;
    move_uploaded_file ($_FILES['userfile'] ['tmp_name'], $uploads_dir);
} else {
    echo "\n Upload Error";
    echo "filename '". $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'] . "'.";
    print_r($_FILES);
```

JAVA code

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost postMethod = new HttpPost("http://localhost/Upload/index.php");

File file = new File(filePath);

MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity();
FileBody contentFile = new FileBody(file);
entity.addPart("userfile",contentFile);

StringBody contentString = new StringBody("This is contentString");
entity.addPart("contentString",contentString);

postMethod.setEntity(entity);
HttpResponse response = client.execute(postMethod);
HttpEntity httpEntity = response.getEntity();
String state = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
```

Answer (score 0):

At finish I got upload photos with the following example, I put the code for if it is necessary for somebody:
http://www.internetria.com/blog/2013/04/12/android-enviar-imagenes-por-webservice/

It is in Spanish, but if there are any doubt, ask me.